# Call a function with vectors as the argument when the scope of the vectors is within a loop and I don't want to loop the calling of the function

Tags: c++, function, vector

Please help! I'm truly at a loss for what to do in this situation!

Disclaimer: In case you can't tell, I'm a beginner and my professor is not helpful.

Here's what should be happening:

> The program should dynamically read string input from the user for an unknown number of times inside of a do-while loop. The loop will run until the user types the word GO. Each index of the string is read into a vector of the char data type. A vector of a vector reads in each line of the first vector.
>
> Example:
>
> Input: "APPLE", "BANANA", "MANGO"
>
> 2D Vector:
>
> ```
>    0 1 2 3 4 5 6
> 0  A P P L E
> 1  B A N A N A
> 2  M A N G O
> ```
>
> After the 2D vector is filled, the outputs of the vector should then be displayed. e.g.
>
> ```
> APPLE  
> BANANA  
> MANGO
> ```

The problem is that the 2D vector is defined within the scope of the `for` loops that are filling it, so I can't access the vector anywhere else.

I have a function called `printVector` that should display the contents, but I can only call it within the loop. I don't want to call it from within the loop, because the contents only need to display one time after all the input has been collected.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

char printVector(vector <vector<char>> word_rows, vector<char>word_columns);

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter each word." << endl;
    cout << "At the end of each word, press Enter" << endl;
    cout << "When all of the words have been entered, type GO " << endl;

    string line;
    cin >> line;

    do
    {
        int count = 1;
        vector <vector<char>> word_rows;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            count += 1;
            vector<char>word_columns;
            for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++)
            {
                word_columns.push_back(line.at(i));
            }
            word_rows.push_back(word_columns);
        }
        cin >> line;
    } while (line != "GO");

}

char printVector(vector <vector<char>> word_rows, vector<char>word_columns)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < word_rows.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < word_rows[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << word_rows[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: So define the vector outside of the loop? What is the problem with doing that?

Comment: Move `word_rows` to the same place as `line`, that should solve it.

Comment: **DECLARE** the vector *before* the loop, then **FILL** the vector *inside* the loop, then **DISPLAY** the vector *after* the loop.

Comment: Wouldn't `std::string line; std::cin >> line; std::vector<std::vector<char>> lines; do { lines.emplace_back(line.begin(), line.end()); std::cin >> line; } while(line != "GO"); for (auto const& l : lines) { std::cout << std::string_view(l.data(), l.size()) << '\n'; }` do the trick... Btw: not sure why your professor is insisting on a `do ... while();` loop. There's no mention of what's supposed to happen, if the first input is `GO`. If this means nothing should be printed, then you'd basically need to turn the do while into a regular while loop by wrapping it in `if(line != "GO") { ... }`